# Making a world map with plots based on the density, using ggmap

Tags: r

I want to make a world map centered on Japan with plots based on the number or density, using ggmap.I want to create something like this:

[image]

The data I want to use is:

```
df  <- read.table(header=F, text=" Japan   3137
 China   542
 Korea   499
 VietNam   423
 Indonesia   261
 Thailand   222
 SriLanka   60
 Taiwan   56
 Taiwan   60
 Bangladesh   51
  Nepal   43
 India   37
 Mongolia   26
 Myanmar  21
 Philippines   16
 Singapore   15
 Cambodia   11
 Malaysia   10
 Pakistan   9
 Lao_People_Democratic_Republic   7
 Brunei_Darussalam   3
 Afghanistan   10
 Iran   2
 Yemen   2
 United_Arab_Emirates   2
 Lebanon   1
 Israel   1
 Kenya   9
 Botswana   7
 Ethiopia   3
 Nigeria   2
 Mozambique   2
  Uganda   2
 Morocco   1
 Ghana   1
 South_Africa   1
 Zimbabwe   1
 America   58
 Canada   5
 UnitedMexicanStates   5
 Brazil   2
 Guyana   2
 AntiguaandBarbuda   1
 Cuba   1
 Nicaragua   1
  Fiji   11
 Australia   6
 Tonga   6
 Samoa   2
 PapuaNewGuinea   1
  Uzbekistan   106
 Norway   10
 KyrgyzRepublic   9
 Germany   7
 Fracne   6
 Tajikistan   6
 Austria   5
 Italy   5
 UK   5
 Belgium   4
 Denmark   4
 Sweden   4
 Finland   4
 Estonia   3
 Lithuania   3
 Russia   3
 Georgia   1
 Netherlands   1
 Portuguese   1
 Iceland   1
 Kazakhstan   1
 Moldova   1
 Poland   1
 Spain   1
 SwissConfedeartion   1
 Ukraine   1")
```

I typed: require(maps)

```
     world_map <- map_data("df")
```

I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: You asked a question related to this earlier today.  What did you learn from the SO questions listed there?  What have you tried?  Have you looked online for tutorials or guidance?

Comment: There have actually been quite a few geo-oriented blog posts aggregated by r-bloggers over the past few months. Have you looked at any of those?

Comment: I am sorry. I really do not know how to do this.

Comment: Oh, those country names. Painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After re-reading the question, there are enough interesting (& relatively tough) parts to it that I thought a more complete answer might be useful to the broader SO community. Also, since the OP has no idea how to even plot points on a normal map, using a re-centered map would be that much more difficult to grok.

The first bit of code uses a world map shapefile that's been re-centered to the Pacific (look [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79447/how-to-change-shapefile-longitude-from-180-180-to-0-360) for some techniques on how to do that with `ogr`). It also removes antarctica.

```
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(httr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(countrycode)

# Get Pacific-centered map & remove Antarctica ----------------------------

world_0_360_geojson <- "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hrbrmstr/1caee1f5e95cc8fa70c2/raw/f4cdd7f34d3a4512cb1c66345d9a5d6149c05c7c/world_0_360.json"
stop_for_status(GET(world_0_360_geojson, write_disk("world_0_360.geojson"), progress()))                

world <- readOGR("world_0_360.geojson", "OGRGeoJSON")
world <- world[!world$iso_a2 %in% c("AQ"),]

world_map <- fortify(world)
```

The next bit of code takes that awful line of countries and values and tries to make some sense of it. +100 to the `countrycode` package for having enough regex-fu to make sense of most of the country names. **NOTE: it doesn't catch them all, so you'll need to do some of your own data transformation.**

It also grabs the centroids from the countries in our shapefile, but **you'll probably want to change a couple of those as well** (since—for one example—I think you'll want the lower-48 states geographic US center instead of the whole one).

```
# Transform our country data ----------------------------------------------

proportions <- "Japan 3137 China 542 Korea 499 VietNam 423 Indonesia 261 Thailand 222 SriLanka 60 Taiwan 56 Taiwan 60 Bangladesh 51 Nepal 43 India 37 Mongolia 26 Myanmar 21 Philippines 16 Singapore 15 Cambodia 11 Malaysia 10 Pakistan 9 Lao_People_Democratic_Republic 7 Brunei_Darussalam 3 Afghanistan 10 Iran 2 Yemen 2 United_Arab_Emirates 2 Lebanon 1 Israel 1 Kenya 9 Botswana 7 Ethiopia 3 Nigeria 2 Mozambique 2 Uganda 2 Morocco 1 Ghana 1 South_Africa 1 Zimbabwe 1 America 58 Canada 5 UnitedMexicanStates 5 Brazil 2 Guyana 2 AntiguaandBarbuda 1 Cuba 1 Nicaragua 1 Fiji 11 Australia 6 Tonga 6 Samoa 2 PapuaNewGuinea 1 Uzbekistan 106 Norway 10 KyrgyzRepublic 9 Germany 7 Fracne 6 Tajikistan 6 Austria 5 Italy 5 UK 5 Belgium 4 Denmark 4 Sweden 4 Finland 4 Estonia 3 Lithuania 3 Russia 3 Georgia 1 Netherlands 1 Portuguese 1 Iceland 1 Kazakhstan 1 Moldova 1 Poland 1 Spain 1 SwissConfedeartion 1 Ukraine 1"

proportions %>%
  strsplit(" ") %>%
  extract2(1) %>%
  matrix(ncol=2, byrow=TRUE) %>%
  as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE) %>%
  select(country=1, value=2) %>%
  mutate(value=as.numeric(value),
         iso_2c=countrycode(country, "country.name", "iso2c")) %>%
  left_join(data.frame(gCentroid(world, byid=TRUE), iso_2c=world@data$iso_a2)) -> pts
```

Then, the last bit of code plots the map and points on the map. It does not use colors for the countries since it's unlikely your audience will be able to tell the nuances of the similarities between many of the colors in the 76+ color palette there would be). If you do need the colors based on "Family" (from your image example), you'll need to figure out which countries belong to which "Family" and then color by that new factor. The map code also uses a `log` scale for the size (based on `value`) since that seems to make more sense.

```
gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(map=world_map, data=world_map,
                    aes(map_id=id, x=long, y=lat))
gg <- gg + geom_point(data=pts, aes(x=x, y=y, size=log(value)), color="red")
gg <- gg + scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
gg <- gg + scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
gg <- gg + labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)
gg <- gg + coord_equal()
gg <- gg + theme_bw()
gg <- gg + theme(panel.border=element_blank())
gg
```

[image]

I deliberately left many of the `ggplot2` defaults in and used an awful red color so you'd have to change them to fit your publication needs.

Comment: Is it possible to change black color to white? When I try to do this,  I get this message: Warning message:
Removed 5 rows containing missing values (geom_point). 
Error in dontCheck(fnname) : 
  VECTOR_ELT() can only be applied to a 'list', not a 'integer'

Comment: For the color change, yes. Add `,color="black", fill="white"` before the last `)` in the `geom_map` call. As I explained in the answer, the name lookup for the horrible country names is not perfect. There are `NA`s which you need to deal with.

Comment: When I type this: gg <- gg + theme(panel.border=element_blank(), ,color="black", fill="white") , I get Error in (function (el, elname)  : 
  "color" is not a valid theme element name. For the country names, should I change China to People's Republic of China, for instance?

Comment: I've helped as much as I think I can. If you're not familiar with `ggplot` then this could get very tedious. It sounds like you really haven't used R much. This was a huge project to take on if that is the case and you might want to take as step back and work on basic R for a while.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any website that contains basic R in order to  practice?